# Create user in Azure SQL database using Azure functions?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I want to create users in Azure SQL database. I am running this PowerShell through Azure Functions.

I have set up my own name as server admin. Also I have configured the firewall.

But I am not able to connect to SQL database.

> It gives me error : Cannot open server "domain.com" requested by the
>   login.  The login failed.

This is my script:

```
$serverName = "servername.database.windows.net"

$databaseName = "databasename"

$adminLogin = 'user@domain.com'

$PWord = "password"

$query = "CREATE USER [user1@domain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;";

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -U $adminLogin -Password $PWord -Query $query
```

I have tried this script as well:

Although below script works in Windows PowerShell, but does not work in Azure functions PowerShell.

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential 'username@domain.com'
    $Username = $($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().UserName)
    $Password = $($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
    $Database = "testg"
    $Server = 'test.database.windows.net'
    $Port = 1433
    $cxnString = "Server=tcp:$Server,$Port;Database=$Database;Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
    $query = "CREATE USER YourUser WITH PASSWORD = 'JRxuerCc(q'"
    $cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString)
    $cxn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $cxn.Close()
```

> But this does not work in Azure functions. It say keyword not
>   supported: 'authentication'

Similar way I tried with .NET approach as well. But it gives the same error

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how did you run invoke-sqlcmd in an azure function? I try to import the module but keep getting an error that it's not a valid cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer to this. If anybody still searching for answer here it is

This is currently not possible with PowerShell in azure functions.

I had to do this with .net core.

key here is to use **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** package. 
System.Data.SqlClient does not support active directory password authentication.

Use this Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package and bingo!

code goes here :

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            string userName = "username@domain.com";
            string password = "password";
            builder.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:" + server + ",1433;Database=" + database + ";Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=" + userName + ";PWD=" + password + ";Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "CREATE USER YourUser WITH PASSWORD = 'JRxuerCc(q'"
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
```